# Missing number in a 4x4 grid

Tags: missing-digits

I am trying to solve this puzzle for the missing number. Tried different combinations of addition/multiplication/subtraction in each column. But could not solve it. Can any one help?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 | 6 | 5 |
| 9 | 7 | 5 | 8 |
| 5 | 8 | 2 | 45 |
| 41 | 46 | 52 | ? |

Comment: Did this puzzle come with any constraints or a goal?

Comment: These are all the digits.. note that `0` and `3` are missing: `1 2 2 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9`